Not getting the inbox domain using linkedin api
I created a linkedin dev app with this scope: Member Data Portability API (Member)
Now I am making a request to see all domains it return. Getting this:
LinkedIn Member Snapshot Domain Summary:
========================================
CONTACTS: 782 item(s)
COURSES: 8 item(s)
EDUCATION: 5 item(s)
EMAIL_ADDRESSES: 1 item(s)
ENDORSEMENTS: 3204 item(s)
Events: 22 item(s)
INFERENCE_TAKEOUT: 17 item(s)
INSTANT_REPOSTS: 18 item(s)
INVITATIONS: 1382 item(s)
JOB_APPLICANT_SAVED_ANSWERS: 2 item(s)
JOB_APPLICATIONS: 22 item(s)
JOB_POSTINGS: 4 item(s)
JOB_SEEKER_PREFERENCES: 2 item(s)
LANGUAGES: 2 item(s)
LEARNING: 801 item(s)
MEMBER_FOLLOWING: 304 item(s)
MEMBER_HASHTAG: 6 item(s)
MEMBER_POSTS_ABOUT_HASHTAG: 5 item(s)
MEMBER_SHARE_INFO: 256 item(s)
PHONE_NUMBERS: 1 item(s)
POSITIONS: 2 item(s)
PROFILE: 1 item(s)
PROFILE_SUMMARY: 2 item(s)
PROJECTS: 2 item(s)
PUBLICATIONS: 4 item(s)
RECEIPTS: 32 item(s)
RECOMMENDATIONS: 46 item(s)
REGISTRATION: 1 item(s)
SEARCHES: 7719 item(s)
SECURITY_CHALLENGE_PIPE: 32 item(s)
SKILLS: 19 item(s)
TALENT_QUESTION_SAVED_RESPONSE: 8 item(s)
login: 702 item(s)

From the docs it says that I should have access to "INBOX", which I don't have. Its been 2 weeks now, so that should be enough time for it to be available, right?
Ran this code and got the result above:
BASE_URL = "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/memberSnapshotData"

def get_member_snapshot_summary():
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {ACCESS_TOKEN}",
        "LinkedIn-Version": "202312"
    }
    params = {
        "q": "criteria",
        "start": 0,
        "count": 100  # Increased to get more data per request
    }
    
    domain_summary = defaultdict(int)
    total_elements = 0
    
    while True:
        response = requests.get(BASE_URL, headers=headers, params=params)
        
        if response.status_code == 404 and "No data found for this memberId" in response.text:
            print("Reached the end of available data.")
            break
        
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
            print(response.text)
            break
        
        data = response.json()
        
        for element in data['elements']:
            domain = element['snapshotDomain']
            domain_summary[domain] += len(element['snapshotData'])
        
        total_elements += len(data['elements'])
        
        # Check for next page
        next_link = next((link for link in data['paging']['links'] if link['rel'] == 'next'), None)
        if not next_link:
            break
        
        # Update start parameter for next page
        params['start'] = int(next_link['href'].split('start=')[1])
        
        print(f"Processed page starting at {params['start']}")
    
    return domain_summary, total_elements

